# Postgres column encrypt error - invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3

Tags: postgresql, encryption, utf-8

I am trying to encrypt a Postgres table column using my own algorithms. I am reading rsa key from file and encrypting data using algorithms.
My column type is bytea.

When I try to insert encrypted data the Postgres gives the following error:

> pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3

I tried few options setting encoding as found on internet but did not work.

I don't know what is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

The salient part of your code consists of these lines:

```
$ec = SaferCrypto::encrypt($c, $k);
```

So `$ec` presumably contains binary at this point.
And so the rest is wrong:

```
$query = "INSERT into enc_test values('$ec')";
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
```

because you're trying to pass binary contents directly in the text of a query. The value must be encoded in a text representation to be injected as a literal into the query's values clause.

This should be done with the [`pg_escape_bytea()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-bytea.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to store binary data in a string (`text`, `character varying`, …) column.

PostgreSQL rejects data that do not match the encoding set by the parameter `client_encoding`. If you study [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), you will find that no character can start with 0xa3 (binary 10100011) in UTF-8.

The solution is to use a column of type `bytea` (byte array) to store binary data.

Comment: Could you show the complete insert statement and table definition?